# Google maps is telling me invalid size parameter

Tags: windows

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400X400&location=10+FALLING+CREEK,THOMASVILLE,NC&sensor=FALSE

I can run this URL but when I try and run it using windows command line I get this message that size parameter is invalid above is the URL that I use. It works when I build it in a word document or when I send an e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

parameters seem to be case sensitive, try

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location=10+FALLING+CREEK,THOMASVILLE,NC&sensor=false

i.e. lowercase *x* for *size* parameter and lowercase *false* for *sensor* parameter